# Auth via wget works, but cannot navigate inside webpage after it

Tags: wget

I can get a cookie, ok:

```
wget -q --tries=5 --retry-connrefused --timeout=29 -U 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0' --no-check-certificate --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies cookies.txt --post-data 'email=foo@bar.com&password=ASDF' HTTPS://FOO.BAR -O - > /dev/null 2>&1
```

But when I try to surf with the cookie.. IT ONLY WORKS when I log in via a webbrowser too! (and if I log out of the website in the webbrowser it doesn't work anymore)

```
wget -q --tries=5 --retry-connrefused --timeout=29 -U 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0' --no-check-certificate --keep-session-cookies --load-cookies cookies.txt -p "HTTPS://FOO.BAR/somewhere" -O out.html
```

**My question**: Why does wget only work if I am logged in the website too? Maybe there is another auth mode that is only working in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like they're able to detect that you're not using an actual browser, even though you're setting an explicit user agent.

I would use a tool such as [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm), a Chrome extension, to make sure you've fully captured the headers that are being sent back and forth to this site and your browser. There is likely some aspect that's different between your browser traffic and your `wget` traffic.

You can also use Wireshark or `tshark` to spy on the traffic as well.